# User must choose department on login

Tags: fusionauth

I'm trying to analyse FusionAuth as possible Identity manager for our current solution.
Our current solution is deployed at customer premisses or cloud, and helps them manage their processes (with their company users).
Our current solution is in early-transformation for micro-service solution, and we're trying to extract the user + authentication flow first. We thought maybe using some JWT solution for authentication could be a thing.

We have the use case that companies may have different root-level departments, and an user may belong to more than one department (or its children departments)
How currently is solved, is that at login time if such an user is making the login then it has to choose which root-level department he wants to login into.
We would expect that our new solution with JWT would contain such high-level department on the token information
Users logged-in for a root-level department can't access all data from other departments (only some base data)

I'm trying to understand if such use case could be acomplished by tenants / applications / groups, but I don't see how the same user could belong to many of them and have the possibility to choose one of them at login time

Would anyone suggest an approach to the problem, and if Fusion Auth could solve it?

Also some of our customers do use LDAP, and ask us to integrate the login through their AD (we make the login with AD, and import / synchronize the users). I've seen an open issue for AD integration, but not sure if that is going to be adopted?

Comment: Does the selection of the department need to be on the login form or can you move this to a secondary step after the login is successful?

Comment: I'm debating about that as well.. 
the requirement would be that generated JWT should contain the selected department.

currently, at the GUI, this is done in 2 step process... first authenticate then fetch all its department, then select department.

but for API calls sometimes the institute already comes pre-selected as additional information to the Basic header...

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to present the user with a Department Select Screen prior to sending them to FusionAuth. This screen would list out the Departments and the user would select one. Once they select the Department, they would be redirected to FusionAuth's OAuth where the Department is the `client_id`. This also means that you need a FusionAuth Application for each Department.

Once the user has logged into FusionAuth, the JWT that FusionAuth creates will contain the Application id. This will allow you to identify the Department that they logged into.